# Exchange 2010 purging client subscriptions using EWS

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange

### Scenario

I have a console service responsible for maintaining a streaming subscription to our Exchange 2010 SP1 server. I've properly hooked up my events (notification, error, disconnect) using the Exchange Web Services SDK 1.1.

### Problem

When I try and re-establish my subscription I will sometimes (no pattern as far as I can see) I will receive an exception saying that I do not have an active subscription. Sometimes I can go through 10 reconnect cycles no problem and other times it tries to reconnect once and my subscription magically disappears.

I've tested against our QA server and I am able to successfully reinitialize my subscription once I get disconnected (due to the timeout). However, our production server appears to be having a real hard time keeping a subscription.

### Question

Does Exchange 2010 SP1 have some sort of odd mechanism where it will simply remove subscriptions once the client is disconnected? Since I'm pretty sure this is the case how do you disable such thing?

This question is related to something I asked earlier today on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911904/where-is-my-streaming-subscription-going). After some more thinking and playing around with our QA and production environment I believe it might be a settings issue with Exchange.

Edit: This is issue is still not fully resolved. I managed to manually resubscribe however I'm still intrigued in finding out exactly why my subscriptions are vanishing.

Edit 2: Another related issue is that new mail notification events are not being sent out. Are there any resources I can read regarding client subscriptions with Exchange 2010 SP1?

Edit 3: If it helps we're currently in an upgrade phase where we have an Exchange 2003 and Exchange 2010 server running at the same time. So I'm wondering if it's possible that that's causing the issue as as our QA environment isn't running the identical architecture.

Comment: I'm not sure the proper way to bump a question but figure I'd try before the bounty expires.

Answer (score 1):

a) You can take a look at this cmdlet - Get-ThrottlingPolicy. It has MaxTimeinAD and other keys which can be modified. More details here.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2011/06/23/exchange-online-throttling-and-limits-faq.aspx

b) How can you control EWS Access.

- Per Mailbox> Run this from Exchange shell `get-casmailbox -identity:"username" | fl "*EWS*`
  You can disable those keys using a set-mailbox -identity:"username" -EWSEnabled: $False
- The whole organization: `Get-OrganizationConfig | fl *EWS*
- You can play around with this, with a list of mailboxes to modify in CSV, and then importing the CSV > and piping out all mailboxes one by one to set-casmailbox.

c) New Mail Notification is a client side feature, so you need to check outlook / phone settings.

b) During Exchange 2003-2010 co-existence, are all mails routed through 2010 or 2003. Also did you setup the CAS role and tested OWA access ?